# Change select last option become first option in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

i have a select option using oop that i not familiar with. i want to change last option become first option.
the actual coding is like below :

```
  <select class="terms" id="terms{VAL_ID}">
        <option class="term">Term</option>
    </select>
```

it will display like this :

```
<select class="terms" id="128035">
   <option class="term" id="1">ans1</option>
   <option class="term" id="2">ans2</option>
   <option class="term" id="-1">-- Please Select --</option>
</select>
```

my problem is, i want to make last choice to become first choice using javascript they used. Below the script. If anyone can help me alter the script to make last option become first option. Thanks

```
<script>
    function renderILQuestion{VAL_ID}()
    {
        jQuery('div#qtitle{VAL_ID}').html(questions[{VAL_ID}].question);

        var terms_dir = {
            'option': {
                'term <- terms': {
                    '.': 'term.term',
                    '@id':'term.id'}
            }};


        jQuery('#terms{VAL_ID}').render(questions[{VAL_ID}].pairs[0], terms_dir);

        var pairs_dir = {
            'tbody tr': {
                'pair <- pairs': {
                    'th.definition': 'pair.definition',
                    'select@id':'pair.def_id'}
            }};
        jQuery('#container{VAL_ID}').render(questions[{VAL_ID}], pairs_dir);
    }

    renderILQuestion{VAL_ID}();

    var obj = document.getElementsByClassName("terms");

</script>
```

Comment: `function renderILQuestion{VAL_ID}()` this is certainly not a *valid* name...

Comment: you can check the code here : http://phpcrossref.com/xref/ilias/Modules/Scorm2004/templates/default/tpl.question_export.html.html

Comment: you should have stated that this code was interpolated by a templating system. You need to re-tag your question, and include more of the code in the question.

Comment: i just need to modify the script, no need whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I invite you to check the [`selectors` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), & by the way here is a working code:

```js
$(".terms").each(function(){
$(this).find("option:last").prop("selected",true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="terms" id="128035">
   <option class="term" id="11">ans1</option>
   <option class="term" id="21">ans2</option>
   <option class="term" id="-11">-- Please Select --</option>
</select>

<select class="terms" id="ABCD">
   <option class="term" id="12">ans1</option>
   <option class="term" id="22">ans2</option>
   <option class="term" id="-12">-- Please Select --</option>
</select>


<select class="terms" id="ABCDE">
   <option class="term" id="13">ans1</option>
   <option class="term" id="23">ans2</option>
   <option class="term" id="-13">-- Please Select --</option>
</select>


<select class="terms" id="ABCDEF">
   <option class="term" id="14">ans1</option>
   <option class="term" id="24">ans2</option>
   <option class="term" id="-14">-- Please Select --</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i know this working, just to ask.. what if i have two select with same class terms different id in one page... does this working?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea of oop, but I guess you can change that option position after the select is set...

```
$('select.terms option').last().prependTo('select.terms');
$('select.terms')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

I hope it helps